# Realm Collection Insertion for UI Update

Tags: swift, realm

If you look at the Realm docs for Swift, the [Interface-driven Writes section](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#interface-driven-writes) indicates that you can observe a `collection`:

```
// Add fine-grained notification block
token = collection.observe { changes in
  switch changes {

  case .initial:
    tableView.reloadData()

  case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
    // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
    tableView.beginUpdates()

    // Always apply updates in the following order: deletions, insertions, then modifications.
    // Handling insertions before deletions may result in unexpected behavior.
    tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                          with: .automatic)
    tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                          with: .automatic)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                          with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()

  case .error(let error):
    // handle error
    ()
  }
}
```

I assume this to mean the `collection` is of type `Results<Item>!`.

But right below that, it demonstrates a way to perform a `write` while allowing the UI to update instantly:

```
func insertItem() throws {
  // Perform an interface-driven write on the main thread, making sure 
  // the change notification doesn't apply the change a second time
  try collection.realm!.write(withoutNotifying: [token]) {
    collection.insert(Item(), at: 0)
  }

  // And mirror it instantly in the UI instead
  tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

But what doesn't make sense is that in this case, `collection` has an `insert` method which isn't available on a `Results<Item>!` type, only on an array.

Is there a type that can be observed and inserted to? If not, do I just have to manage my own array and keep `Results<Item>!` in sync with my own `[Item]` array?

Comment: Let me clarify: You have two options for updating your UI - I call them Manual and Automatic. 1) Manual - write the data to realm using withoutNotifying and then manually update your UI - this would be 'instant' since you control when that happens 2) Automatic - write the data to realm and then let the observer on that data update the UI based on the event returned from realm. This would be 'delayed' because it will happen based on the timing of receiving the event. In practice, Realm is pretty darn fast so that 'delay' is generally imperceptible. Where is would apply is for UI animations.

Comment: The way the Collection docs are written is a little confusing (IMO). I would suggest reading [Collections](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collections) to get some context first. Keep in mind that a RealmCollection is a protocol that ensures the classes conform and behave similarly and AnyRealmCollection is a 'generic' collection of stuff. A better example would be `try realm.write(withoutNotifying:` and then, instead of this `collection.insert(Item()` do this `myList.insert(Item()`. So if a Person had a Dogs List, to insert a dog at index 0 it would be `person.dogs.insert(newDog, at: 0)`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you. So in reality, Realm shouldn't have used the same `collection` variable twice because it gives the wrong idea. Do you always move your `Results<Person>` into an array of `[Person]` (for example) when you use Realm?

Comment: lol. Well. There *is* a point to the code they used in that section but it's not as common use case - what you see in my comment is used more frequently. Let me move my comment and a followup comment to an answer so I can incorporate some code.

Answer (score 1):

Let me attempt to clarify:

There are two (or more) options for updating your UI. I call them 'Manual' and 'Automatic'.

1) Manual - write the data to realm using withoutNotifying and then manually update your UI. That would be 'instant' since you control when the happens

2) Automatic - write the data to realm and then let the observer on that data update the UI based on the event returned from realm. This would be 'delayed' because it will happen based on the timing of receiving the event. In practice, Realm is pretty darn fast so that 'delay' is generally imperceptible. Where it may be more applicable is during UI animations where you want them to start immediately instead of waiting a bit before starting (1/2 second or less?)

To answer the question in the comment

> Do you always move your Results into an array of [Person] (for
>   example) when you use Realm?

You should rarely if ever, 'move' results to an array - or use Swift functions to deal with Realm objects.

Realm objects are lazily loaded - so if there's 100,000 objects in Realm using Realm Functions to work with objects, sorting, filtering will have minimual impact.

However, as soon as you implement Swift functions to work with that data, it's all loaded in as one big hunk of data which could overwhelm the device.

So take a look at this additional reason to keep results as results. Suppose you have a PersonClass realm object and you want to retrieve all person objects that have a first_name of Leroy.

Here's the Realm Functions

```
let realmResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).filter("first_name == 'Leroy'")
let realmResultsType = type(of: realmResults)
print(realmResultsType)
```

and then using a Swift filter

```
let swiftResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).filter { $0.first_name == "Leroy" }
let swiftResultsType = type(of: swiftResults)
print(swiftResultsType)
```

and then the output

```
Results<PersonClass>
LazyFilterSequence<Results<PersonClass>>
```

You'll notice the object types are different. If wanted to then add an observer to those objects to watch for changes, you can do that directly with the realm Results

```
self.notificationToken = self.realmResults!.observe { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
```

but not with the LazyFilterSequence.